# Number of solutions to $x^n=e$ in group G is divisible by n, where n divides o(G)

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, group-homomorphism, frobenius-groups

It is straightforward if G is abelian, but appears to be difficult to prove for non-abelian groups. Since, it has been asked in supplementary exercise of Herstein's group theory, I guess some elementary group theoretic proof exists. Can anyone please give me hint. I will be grateful.

Comment: This is a famous theorem of the German group theoretician Ferdinand Frobenius (1849-1917). See for example here for a proof https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/3004416017467.pdf.bannered.pdf